# How to create dynamic table with JSON data?

Tags: javascript, json, html-table

I have a HTML table which I am making with the help of JSON data, I am creating my table with the help of javascript only and my table is dynamic

I have a  array of json inside which I have several objects which are having the data.

from this JSON I am trying to make a HTML table

- I have successfully created the header but facing issue in creating the body part
- I am trying to create this kind of table:

  [image: table]
- Average is like sum of all cancelled bills divided by no.of outlet, that's why I am calculating length of outlets and storing it in a global variable
- As my code is bit of long I have commented my all lines where I am doing what and facing what issues where
- Inside the body part I don't know how can I populate the canceled bills data with respect to outlet and same for duplicate bills also

This is what I have done till now:

```js
var outletCount = 0; //global variable to get the no of outlets
var data = [{
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "cancelled": 126544,
    "duplicate": 1
  },
  {
    "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM",
    "cancelled": 31826,
    "duplicate": 31
  },
  {
    "outlet": "KOLAR",
    "cancelled": 10374,
    "duplicate": 10
  }
];

let formatData = function(data) { //outlets is unique thats why formating it to loop forward in my code
  let outlets = [];
  data.forEach(element => {
    if (outlets.indexOf(element.outlet) == -1) {
      outlets.push(element.outlet);
    }
  });
  outletCount = outlets.length //calculating outlet count

  return {
    data: data,
    outlets: outlets,

  };
};

let renderTable = function(data) {
  outlets = data.outlets;
  data = data.data;
  let tbl = document.getElementById("tblOlSalesSummary");
  let table = document.createElement("table");
  let thead = document.createElement("thead");
  let headerRow = document.createElement("tr");
  let th = document.createElement("th");
  th.innerHTML = "Bill Type"; //header
  th.classList.add("text-center");
  headerRow.appendChild(th);
  th = document.createElement("th");
  th.innerHTML = "Average"; //header
  th.classList.add("text-center");
  headerRow.appendChild(th);
  outlets.forEach(element => {
    th = document.createElement("th");
    th.innerHTML = element; //this one is populating outlet as header
    th.classList.add("text-center");

    headerRow.appendChild(th);

  });

  thead.appendChild(headerRow);
  table.appendChild(thead);

  let tbody = document.createElement("tbody"); // from here onwards i don't know what to do

  let row = document.createElement("tr");

  let total = 0;
  outlets.forEach(outlet => { //i am trying to loop through outlets but getting somthing else
    let el = 0;
    data.forEach(d => {
      if (d.outlet == outlet) {
        total += parseInt(d.cancelled);
        el = d.cancelled;
      }
    });
    td = document.createElement("td");
    td.innerHTML = el.toLocaleString('en-in');
    td.classList.add("text-right");
    row.appendChild(td);
  });
  /* console.log("row is : " , row.children ) */

  tbody.appendChild(row);


  table.appendChild(tbody);
  tbl.innerHTML = "";
  tbl.appendChild(table);
  table.classList.add("table");
  table.classList.add("table-striped");
  table.classList.add("table-bordered");
  table.classList.add("table-hover");
}
let formatedData = formatData(data);
renderTable(formatedData);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div align="center" class="table table-responsive">
  <table id="tblOlSalesSummary"></table>
</div>
```

I am not getting the point to loop my canceled bill and duplicate bill with respect to outlets and then calculate average.

Comment: Is your table layout only this one or is it dynamic? because if you want to reuse it then it might make sense to use an external library or to format your json response to be more appropriate for table formats

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were two static field column in your table `billtype` and `average` which needed to be appended before looping the json data

```js
 var outletCount = 0; //global variable to get the no of outlets
var data = [{
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "cancelled": 126544,
    "duplicate": 1
  },
  {
    "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM",
    "cancelled": 31826,
    "duplicate": 31
  },
  {
    "outlet": "KOLAR",
    "cancelled": 10374,
    "duplicate": 10
  },
  {
    "outlet": "New Test",
    "cancelled": 154,
    "duplicate": 20
  }
];

let formatData = function(data) { //outlets is unique thats why formating it to loop forward in my code
  let outlets = [];
  data.forEach(element => {
    if (outlets.indexOf(element.outlet) == -1) {
      outlets.push(element.outlet);
    }
  });
  outletCount = outlets.length //calculating outlet count

  return {
    data: data,
    outlets: outlets,

  };
};

let renderTable = function(data) {
  outlets = data.outlets;
  data = data.data;
  let tbl = document.getElementById("tblOlSalesSummary");
  let table = document.createElement("table");
  let thead = document.createElement("thead");
  let headerRow = document.createElement("tr");
  let th = document.createElement("th");
  th.innerHTML = "Bill Type"; //header
  th.classList.add("text-center");
  headerRow.appendChild(th);
  th = document.createElement("th");
  th.innerHTML = "Average"; //header
  th.classList.add("text-center");
  headerRow.appendChild(th);
  outlets.forEach(element => {
    th = document.createElement("th");
    th.innerHTML = element; //this one is populating outlet as header
    th.classList.add("text-center");

    headerRow.appendChild(th);

  });

  thead.appendChild(headerRow);
  table.appendChild(thead);

  let tbody = document.createElement("tbody"); // from here onwards i don't know what to do

  let row = document.createElement("tr");

  let total = 0;

  // static field insertion for Cancelled bill
  let el = 'Cancelled bill';
  td = document.createElement("td");
  td.innerHTML = el.toLocaleString('en-in');
  td.classList.add("text-right");
  row.appendChild(td);
  // Logic start to find the average cancelled amount 
  var total_cancel =0;
  total_can_count = 0;
  outlets.forEach(outlet => { 
    data.forEach(d => {
      if (d.outlet == outlet) {
        total_cancel += parseInt(d.cancelled);
        total_can_count++;

      }
    });
  });

  let el_avg = ( total_cancel / (total_can_count) );
  td = document.createElement("td");
  td.innerHTML = el_avg.toLocaleString('en-in');
  td.classList.add("text-right");
  row.appendChild(td);
  // Logic End to find the average cancelled amount 

  outlets.forEach(outlet => { 
    let el = 0;
    data.forEach(d => {
      if (d.outlet == outlet) {
        total += parseInt(d.cancelled);
        el = d.cancelled;
      }
    });
    td = document.createElement("td");
    td.innerHTML = el.toLocaleString('en-in');
    td.classList.add("text-right");
    row.appendChild(td);
  });

  
  /* console.log("row is : " , row.children ) */

  tbody.appendChild(row);

  let row_duplicate = document.createElement("tr");

  let total_dup = 0;
  // static field insertion for duplicate bill
  let el_2 = 'Duplicate bill';
  td = document.createElement("td");
  td.innerHTML = el_2.toLocaleString('en-in');
  td.classList.add("text-right");
  row_duplicate.appendChild(td);

  // Logic start to find the Duplicate average  
  total_dup_count = 0;
  outlets.forEach(outlet => { 
    data.forEach(d => {
      if (d.outlet == outlet) {
        total_dup += parseInt(d.duplicate);
        total_dup_count++;
      }
    });
  });

  let el_avg_2 = ( total_dup / (total_dup_count) );
  td = document.createElement("td");
  td.innerHTML = el_avg_2.toLocaleString('en-in');
  td.classList.add("text-right");
  row_duplicate.appendChild(td);

  // Logic End to find the Duplicate average  

  outlets.forEach(outlet => { //i am trying to loop through outlets but getting somthing else
    let el = 0;
    data.forEach(d => {
      if (d.outlet == outlet) {
        total += parseInt(d.duplicate);
        el = d.duplicate;
      }
    });
    td = document.createElement("td");
    td.innerHTML = el.toLocaleString('en-in');
    td.classList.add("text-right");
    row_duplicate.appendChild(td);
  });


  /* console.log("row is : " , row.children ) */

  tbody.appendChild(row);
  tbody.appendChild(row_duplicate);

  table.appendChild(tbody);
  tbl.innerHTML = "";
  tbl.appendChild(table);
  table.classList.add("table");
  table.classList.add("table-striped");
  table.classList.add("table-bordered");
  table.classList.add("table-hover");
}
let formatedData = formatData(data);
renderTable(formatedData);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div align="center" class="table table-responsive">
  <table id="tblOlSalesSummary"></table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've written the code in this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/thanthu/8gLd2nuz/38/). Take a look. It uses JQuery.

**HTML:**

```
<table id="dataTable">

</table>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var data = [{
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "cancelled": 126544,
    "duplicate": 1
  },
  {
    "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM",
    "cancelled": 31826,
    "duplicate": 31
  },
  {
    "outlet": "KOLAR",
    "cancelled": 10374,
    "duplicate": 10
  }
];


function draw() {
    var avgCancelled = 0;
    var avgDuplicate = 0;
    var totalCancelled = 0;
    var totalDuplicate = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        totalCancelled += data[i].cancelled;
        totalDuplicate += data[i].duplicate;
    }
    avgCancelled = totalCancelled / data.length;
    avgDuplicate = totalDuplicate / data.length;
    drawTableHead()
    drawTableRows(avgCancelled, avgDuplicate)
}

function drawTableHead() {
    var row = $("<tr />");
    $("#dataTable").append(row);
    row.append("<th>" + "BILLTYPE"  + "</th>")
    row.append("<th>" + "AVERAGE"  + "</th>")
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        row.append("<th>" + data[i].outlet  + "</th>")
    }
}

function drawTableRows(avgCancelled, avgDuplicate) {
    var firstRow = $("<tr />");
    $("#dataTable").append(firstRow);
    firstRow.append("<td>" + "CANCELLED BILL"  + "</td>")
    firstRow.append("<td>" + avgCancelled  + "</td>")
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        firstRow.append("<td>" + data[i].cancelled  + "</td>")
    }
    var secondRow = $("<tr />");
    $("#dataTable").append(secondRow);
    secondRow.append("<td>" + "DUPLICATE BILL"  + "</td>")
    secondRow.append("<td>" + avgDuplicate  + "</td>")
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        secondRow.append("<td>" + data[i].duplicate  + "</td>")
    }
}


draw();
```

Comment: sir i want to calculate average also..like cancelled of (jayanagar+malleshwaram+kolar)/2=avg simillarly for duplicate bill also as i mentioned in my post

Comment: are the columns to be dynamic as shown in image in your question ? like JAYANAGAR,  MALLESHWARAM, KOLAR ...... etc

Comment: yes sir the are dynamic..that's why in my code i was calculating the length of outlets

Comment: hey with this json `[
    {
       "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
       "cancelled": 38993,
       "duplicate": 0
     },
     {
       "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM",
       "cancelled": 10057,
       "duplicate": 9
     },
     {
       "outlet": "KOLAR",
       "cancelled": 3309,
       "duplicate": 2
     }
   ]` it is giving wrong average why?

Comment: I am getting the correct result, replace the data in JSFiddle and run and see the result

Answer (score 0):

Use a library which can do table creation from your json.

Example:

https://json2html.com/

> ```
> <script>
>     var t = {'<>':'div','html':'${title} ${year}'};
>
>     var d = [
>         {"title":"Heat","year":"1995"},
>         {"title":"Snatch","year":"2000"},
>         {"title":"Up","year":"2009"},
>         {"title":"Unforgiven","year":"1992"},
>         {"title":"Amadeus","year":"1984"}
>     ];
>
>     document.write( json2html.transform(d,t) );
> </script>
> ```

Comment: sir i am not allowed to use external library , thats why i am creating my own code with javascript,please help me if you can .